# proxying from containerized production react to containerized flask

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask

I am trying to proxy requests from my containerized React application to my containerized Flask application.

I was starting the application using npm start (in Docker), and I did not have any issues proxying requests. However, I learned that npm start is not a good way to proceed in production.

Following the advice here: [Run a React App in a Docker Container](https://dev.to/peterj/run-a-react-app-in-a-docker-container-kjn) , I am able to start my containerized production React, but now the requests are not proxied.

Within the React app, all requests are handled with axios and are formatted: "/api/v1/endpoint". It seems that others have had issues between "http://localhost:80/api/v1/endpoint" and "/api/v1/endpoint". I do not believe this is my issue, unless it arises only in the production environment.

I have also tried changing my "proxy" address in package.json to the location of the dockerized flask container, and later to the name of the docker container, but I have not been able to make either solution work.

If anyone can provide guidance on launching a containerized, production React app that proxies requests to a backend container, please advise.

I am open to using a different server, if the procedures in "Run a React App in a Docker Container" need to be updated.

I have looked these solutions:

[Proxy React requests to Flask app using Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291655/proxy-react-requests-to-flask-app-using-docker)

[Flask, React in a Docker: How to Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333291/flask-react-in-a-docker-how-to-proxy)

[Posting from React to Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053475/posting-from-react-to-flask)

```
# React Dockerfile

FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR .
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build

FROM node:14-alpine
RUN yarn global add serve
COPY --from=builder build .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["serve", "-p", "3000", "-n", "-s", "."]
```

Comment: The first thing I would check is the networking in docker (are the two containers actually connected to each other?), this can be inspected by checking your `docker run` script. I also believe that using `localhost` is probably wrong, as usually you don't need to proxy anything back to the same container.

Comment: I might try a setup like [Set up nginx proxy for react application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688883/set-up-nginx-proxy-for-react-application) which can serve a compiled React application, and use an Nginx `proxy_pass` request to forward API requests to the back-end application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around and trying a bunch of solutions, here is what worked:

1.) I changed my docker file to run an nginx server:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM node:11.13 as builder

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 -g

COPY ./package-lock.json /usr/src/app/
COPY ./public /usr/src/app/public
COPY ./src /usr/src/app/src

RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.15.10-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /var/www
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And my nginx.conf file:

```
# nginx.conf

events {
    worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
        location /api/ {
            resolver 127.0.0.11;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://my-internal-alb.aws-region.elb.amazonaws.com:80;

            # this may not be necessary?
            proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        }
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location /my-react-endpoint-1 {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location /my-react-endpoint-2 {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe there were two problems. First, I was trying to forward https traffic to my internal load balancer on my private subnet. Second, I believe this was causing problems cross-origin resource sharing, so I also added these lines to my flask application

```
# __init__.py

    api_v1_cors_config = {
        "origins" : [
            'https://my-website.com',
            'http://my-internet-facing-alb.aws-region.amazonaws.com'
        ],
        "methods": ["OPTIONS", "GET", "POST"],
    }

    CORS(flask_app,
         resources={
             "/api/v1/*" : api_v1_cors_config
         })
```

Thank you to David Maze for suggesting I use nginx and proxy pass.